# Add comments to answers from other users

Tags: support, stack-overflow

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do comments work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19756/how-do-comments-work)

I'm a new stackoverflow user and don't see how to add comments to the answers of other users. Is this becouse I havent enought reputation?

Thanks,

Comment: this question should be posted to meta.stackexchange.com (sorry, i dont know the answer to your question)

Answer (score 1):

Check https://stackoverflow.com/faq and read **What is reputation?** section

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is because you don't have enough reputation. You need atleast 50 [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges).